# Technical question about the chain rule

Tags: calculus

Assume we have $ f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ g:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{k} $.

If $ f $ is differentiable and $ g $ is differentiable then

$$ d\left(g\circ f\right)\left(x_{0}\right)=dg\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)\cdot df\left(x_{0}\right) $$

where $dg(f(x_0) $ and $df(x_0)$ are the differentials of $ g$ and $ f$ , at the points $(f(x_0))$ and $(x_0)$ and can be represented as

$$ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f^{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\left(x_{0}\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f^{1}}{\partial x^{m}}\left(x_{0}\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f^n}{\partial x^1}(x_0) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f^{n}}{\partial x^m}(x_0)
\end{pmatrix},\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g^{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial g^{1}}{\partial x^{n}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial g^{k}}{\partial x^{1}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial g^{k}}{\partial x^{n}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)
\end{pmatrix} $$

What confuse me, is for one variable function we do not use the chain rule the way it is described here, because here we differentiate $ g $ by $ x $ and for example if we have $ \cos(x^2) $ we differentiate $ \cos(x^2) $ by $ x^2 $ and then $ x^2 $ by $ x$ , meaning:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^2)=\frac{d}{dx^2}\cos\left(x^2\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}x^2 $$

What do I get wrong here ? why does the differential of $ g $ is not represented as

$$ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g^{1}}{\partial f^{1}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial g^{1}}{\partial f^{n}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial g^{k}}{\partial f^{1}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial g^{k}}{\partial f^{n}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)
\end{pmatrix} \text{ ?} $$

Another example, say we have

$$ f(x(t),y(t))=x^{2t}+ty $$

Then $ \frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} $

Why dont we differentiate here $ f $ by $ x^{2t} $ but rather by just $ x $ and for the one varialbe example with the $ cos $ we differetiate $ \cos $ by $ x^2 $ first and then $ x^2 $ by $ x $

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a 1 by 1 matrix? And what does it mean to multiply two 1 by 1 matrices?

Comment: @jMdA Its not really what I asked, my question is why we differentiate the terms of the matrix of $ g $ by $ x_1,...,x_n $ and not by $ f^1,...,f^n $ like in the one variable case

Comment: @jMdA : That has a standard definition. $\qquad$

Comment: $$
y = \cos u = \cos (x^2)
$$

$$
\frac{dy}{du} = -\sin u \qquad\qquad \frac{du}{dx} = 2x.
$$

$$
\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} = (-\sin u)\cdot 2x = -2x\sin(x^2).
$$

The dependent variable $y$ is differentiated with respect to $u,$ and that is the same as differentiating with respect to $x^2.$

Comment: @MichaelHardy So the right way is actually the representation $ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g^{1}}{\partial f^{1}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial g^{1}}{\partial f^{n}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial g^{k}}{\partial f^{1}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) & \cdots & \frac{\partial g^{k}}{\partial f^{n}}\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)
\end{pmatrix} $ ?

Comment: You wrote: $f(x(t),y(t))=x^{2t}+ty.$ I don't understand this. On the left side, you have $x(t)$ as a function of $t,$ but on the right you have $x$ as one variable and $t$ as another, and $t$ is not an argument to the function $x. \qquad$